# Discovering the hierarchy of shared library dependencies

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, shared-library

I have compiled `caffe` locally, and on trying to run the tests with `make runtests` I get the error:

libcudart.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Note that I have CUDA 8.0 installed, and due to compatibility reasons I cannot install 9.0. So, I do `ldd caffe` to see what is going on, and I can see one line as expected:

```
libcudart.so.8.0 => /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0
```

However, later comes:

```
libcudart.so.9.0 => not found
```

How do I determine which one of my shared modules has the rogue dependency? Can I get a dependency hierarchy somehow to see which module wants 9.0 instead of 8.0?

Comment: `ldd caffe` will only show direct dependencies of `caffe`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Ah, I see. BTW, I found there was a `libopencv_*.so.3.3.1` in `/usr/lib` that depended on CUDA 9, so I deleted them and that fixed the immediate problem. However, it would have been nice to have some way of finding out that it was OpenCV 3.3.1 that was dragging CUDA 9 into the dependency list,